# How to update to the latest bionic beaver in chroot environment

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, upgrade, chroot

I've inherited a load of source code from some contractors. This build works on Ubuntu 18.04.06. Trying to build on previous versions of Ubuntu do not work as package dependencies are missing and the compilation fails. In addition to that every time the build fails, i get stuck in an unsolvable and unfixable horrible npm + nodejs dependency problem that requires the chroot environment (or indeed a server) to be reinstalled.

When I create a chroot environment using:

```
debootstrap bionic 18.04_LTS/
```

Then it installed bionic beaver 18.04 LTS.

And the os-release looks like this:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

That's fine, but I need to upgrade to 18.04.06, but I can't seem to get it to do that. I've tried:

```
apt update
apt upgrade
```

I've tried

```
apt dist-upgrade
```

I've tried

```
apt full-upgrade
```

No matter what i try it stays at 18.04 LTS. But I see from another server that i have 18.04.06 LTS.

Is it possible to upgrade a chrooted ubuntu? Or tell debootstrap to install a specific point release like 18.04.06 rather than just 18.04? Is this a bug?

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_16.x bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
```

and:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Is it just upgraded already and /etc/os-release isn't reporting the latest?

Comment: Please show us the complete output of `sudo apt update` and of `sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: Good point, thanks!

Comment: Your sources are a problem: You have "bionic", but are missing "bionic-updates" and "bionic-security".

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh okay @user535733 i see...